# Angular + Laravel in IIS occurs CROS problem

Tags: angular, laravel, iis

In local XAMPP server,

I can successfully make a POST request to Laravel localhost server through Angular...

Once I upload my Laravel server file in IIS-6, the Angular comes up the error for CROS...

Please tell me what should I do?

I've installed the file for rewrite_amd64.msi in IIS-6 server

Tried to build a new file and only added the CROS plunins - barryvdh/laravel with the setting for Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class to the proper place and it still not works.

Comment: Please check this:
https://therichpost.com/question/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason...

I need to open 'All verbs' not just only GET,POST,OPTION in the php's Module Mapping > Request Restrictions > Verbs